# How can i verify from a command prompt, if a linux host is real or virtual

Tags: linux, virtualization

How would know at command line that the Linux host i logged in to is real machine, with linux installed, or is a virtual machine
Thanks,
-Kamal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VMware Linux Server -- how can you tell if you are a vm or real hardware?](http://serverfault.com/questions/65718/vmware-linux-server-how-can-you-tell-if-you-are-a-vm-or-real-hardware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often `uname -a` will display information that gives you a hint - references to Xen will tell you that you are in that type of virtual machine.

Comment: virtual:Linux dhcp11-167.sfeng.home.com 2.6.32.11sf.p4-4 #1 SMP Fri Sep 17 20:22:25 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: real: Linux bamboo.sd.home.com 2.6.32.11sf.pentM-4 #1 PREEMPT Fri Sep 17 19:50:44 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: `uname -a` certainly won't give you any help if it's running on a VMware server.

Comment: the clue with a vmsserver , is that it will be down ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Try the 'lspci' command; on a virtual machine you'll typically see a bunch of devices that are obviously virtual (e.g. vendor is VMWare or such).

Answer (score 3):

[imvirt](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html), [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) or [facter](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/facter)

Answer (score 3):

I usually use

```
dmidecode --type 1
```

For scripting you might try

```
dmidecode -s system-manufacturer
```