# How can you tell if you are on physical or virtual hardware?

Tags: virtualization, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out if the OS is running in a virtual environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/196958/find-out-if-the-os-is-running-in-a-virtual-environment)

I don't trust my host as far as I can throw them. We are about to move, but I have got this nagging doubt that rather than being on the dedicated machine that we ordered I'm actually on a virtualised machine.

How would I go about proving this one way or the other?

Comment: What OS is the server concerned?

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/196958/, although that one does not assume a hostile provider. If your provider is hostile and _very tricky_, you're pretty much at their mercy.

Comment: Does your contract/service specifiy a dedicated physical machine, because a machine dedicated to your use only, whether physical or virtual, is a dedicated machine as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Note, also, that you might still be virtualized *and* getting an entire dedicated physical machine. There's management (and feature -- like failover) benefits to running your system in a VM even if it's the only one on the machine.

Comment: mattdm is right - whether your server OS is running in a virtual layer may be proof of nothing.  You probably need to weigh up the benefits of pursuing some kind of claim with your host, unless you are just looking to get out of your contract by claiming they breached it somehow.

Comment: Yes this is a dup. Please close. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you are interested it seems it is actually dedicated. Think the support guys are used to dealing with virtualised machines and are using "virtualised" terms in support tickets. That got me suspicious, they are a bunch of cowboys..

Answer (score 3):

For VMWare at least, either have a look at the network adapter type (it should say VMWare) or get the MAC address of the NIC and go [here](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/) to look up the vendor.

Comment: Not that the MAC couldn't be faked or anything.

Comment: sure I admit it isn't a failproof method and there are probably other ways to figure it out, but if they haven't gone through the trouble of intentionally faking it, then it is a quick check

Answer (score 0):

Assume your guest OS is Linux, you can do `dmidecode -s system-manufacturer`. In the case of VMWare it will return `VMware, Inc.`.