# shorewall can'T start: UNTRACKED state requires Raw Table in your kernel and iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, shorewall

I'm trying setting up my firewall and installed and configured shorewall. Unfortunately I tried to directly configure iptables first, but this didn't work.

When I start shorewall, I get this messages ins /var/log/shorewall-init.log:

`Processing /etc/shorewall/params ...
 Processing /etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf...
 ERROR: UNTRACKED state requires Raw Table in your kernel and iptables`

What can I do?

(ubuntu server 14.04.1 LTS in a vm)

Comment: What is the underlying virtualization technology ?

Comment: I exactly don't know, because it's not my v-server. Is there a way to find out withoud having access to the host?

Comment: In the vm you can try virt-what or look here http://serverfault.com/questions/65718/vmware-linux-server-how-can-you-tell-if-you-are-a-vm-or-real-hardware

Comment: It's OpenVZ, contact your provider or use something that isn't OpenVZ. This is only the first of _many_ problems you are going to have.

Comment: @lain my system couldn't find any of the commands mentioned in the thread you wrote... But I'm sure, that this is a v-server hostet by http://www.server4you.com/vps/

at Michael Hampton: How can I detect, if it is OpenVZ?

Comment: http://christian.hofstaedtler.name/blog/2008/10/detecting-openvz.html

Comment: @lain: ok thank you. Unfortunately I'm in a OpenVZ environment :/